# New side menu back to header

Tags: feature-request, design, navigation

New side menu can be very handy but is it possible to place it back to the header where it was before on the top?

From the visual perspective it seems consume the side part of the page from questions/answers.

Comment: I agree, and it reduces area in the Full Post Page.